# WMI query for Counter of type RateOfCountsPerSecond32 shows raw value instead of persecond value

Tags: wmi, performancecounter, requests-per-second

I have created some custom performance counters form my application to record TotalRequest (numberOfItems32) received and Request received per second (rateOfCountsPerSecond32). These 2 counters works fine and displays proper values in the perfmon. However when i use WMI query from logstash plugin the request received per second counter show the raw value instead of the per second value.

1. Can someone explain why WMI is not getting the per second value?
2. Is this a WMI limitation?
3. Is there any workaround to get the per second value from WMI query?

Thanks

Comment: Which `wmi` class(es) do you query?

Comment: Given below is my query SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_MyAppName_MyAppName

Comment: The likelihood is that the problem is in your custom performance counter code, not WMI.

Comment: I am 100% sure that its not from my custom performance counter code. I can see side by side both windows (perfmon and console window of WMI results). Console shows the raw value but on the perfmon the same counter shows the per second value.

Comment: This issue is fixed now by using Win32_PerfFormattedData. Earlier I was using Win32_PerfRawData that's the reason I was getting raw value instead of formatted value. Now my query looks like this  "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_MyAppName_MyAppName"